# Image is not displayed on wp_get_attachment_image_src, instead it returns an array

Tags: wordpress, image, attachment

Hi i have a wordpress site and i am trying to display image using **wp_get_attachment_image_src** but it returns only array

Below what i have tried with myself

```
`$get_story_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "size" );`

if ( $get_story_image_src ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $get_story_image_src ; ?>" alt="story_image" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its correct **wp_get_attachment_image_src**  always returns array .

if you want to display image using this function you need to pass array indexes in the image tag .

Try below code :

```
`$get_story_image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "size" );`

if ( $get_story_image_src ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $get_story_image_src[0]; width="<?php echo $get_story_image_src[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $get_story_image_src[2]; ?>" ?>" alt="story_image" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also its good if you read all the parameters of the functions before you used

Refer this link - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

Comment: WordPress Documentation that states that `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` does NOT always return an array: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/  This is a minor technicality since the truthy check in this answer will be sufficient to exclude `false` values.